# How do I get my c# application to popup a video when user clicks incorrect button?

Tags: c#, video, popup

Im fairly new to programming and I'm doing some tutorials but adding some twists myself to make the programs more useful to me which is keeping me motivated.

I have search but cant find a way to pop up a video when a user clicks button. The button is a rotate button but when the user clicks it without and image to rotate I would like it to play a funny video. Currently it just displays a message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to StackOverflow. **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FULLPATH);
```

The 'FULLPATH' is the full file path of your video file.
By using this method, the video will be opened by using the default application for it.